# How do I find a list of all dictionaries available as XDXF?

Tags: data-request, dictionary

The only reason I know about XDXF is that this dictionary mentions that it supports it: http://folkets-lexikon.csc.kth.se/folkets/om.en.html

Now I'm trying to find all other dictionaries, in many different languages, but primarily English, Swedish, Finnish, Norwegian, Danish, German, French, Dutch, Japanese, Korean, etc. I pretty much want them all. And several ones for each language, if possible, so that I can make a gigantic local database of them and never have to send any individual requests to external websites again, and make all kinds of queries which would not be possible unless hosted locally.

I would then be able to make a nice quick list of words in all kinds of languages based on what I input into my system.

However, I've spent significant time now and not found anything. Just the usual nonsensical, outdated source code repositories with cryptic, undocumented information which has nothing to do with what I'm searching for.

Other than spending weeks manually searching through every online dictionary and click around their websites only to find that maybe a couple of them have XDXF files for download, is there some way for me to get links to them in one location?

Note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDXF has a teasing link called "XDXF dictionaries repository", but it actually links to no such thing.

Comment: "The easiest way to get a prepared XDXF dictionary is to convert any other-format dictionary with the "makedict" tools." https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/xdxf-format/I7YrtQGXLL0

Answer (score 1):

I went through the old Wikipedia edits and found and old link
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=XDXF&oldid=420455117

that’s dead: xdxf.revdanica.com/down/

but that page was archived on the wayback machine
https://web.archive.org/web/20111222190311/http://xdxf.revdanica.com/down/

and I manually checked one download and it was archived, too, so hopefully many are available

Comment: I appreciate it, but those are all links to old copies of dictionaries. Maybe I was unclear, but I meant current URLs which I can keep downloading every few months (automatically, with my script) and update my unified dictionary database.

Answer (score 0):

Another source is here: https://quest-app.appspot.com/download

There are a lot of XDXF dictionaries listed for **QTranslate**.
I do not know if they are taken from the **web.archive.org**,
but the project is alive.